# Magento 2: Apply JS after estimated shipping methods load and change

Tags: magento2.3

On the cart page Estimated shipping methods I have to display custom text using js before the list of shipping methods.

Shipping methods are loading by knockout. So I have to apply jquery after load shipping methods and the same should be applied when the customer changes the shipping country, region, and zip code.

I have changed in
module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/cart/estimate-service.js but jquery not applying.

```
define([
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (quote, defaultProcessor, totalsDefaultProvider, shippingService, cartCache, customerData) {
'use strict';

var rateProcessors = [],
    totalsProcessors = [],

    /**
     * Estimate totals for shipping address and update shipping rates.
     */
    estimateTotalsAndUpdateRates = function () {
        var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();

        if (
            quote.isVirtual() ||
            window.checkoutConfig.activeCarriers && window.checkoutConfig.activeCarriers.length === 0
        ) {
            // update totals block when estimated address was set
            totalsProcessors['default'] = totalsDefaultProvider;
            totalsProcessors[type] ?
                totalsProcessors[type].estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress()) :
                totalsProcessors['default'].estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
        } else {
            // check if user data not changed -> load rates from cache
            if (!cartCache.isChanged('address', quote.shippingAddress()) &&
                !cartCache.isChanged('cartVersion', customerData.get('cart')()['data_id']) &&
                cartCache.get('rates')
            ) {
                shippingService.setShippingRates(cartCache.get('rates'));

                return;
            }

            // update rates list when estimated address was set
            rateProcessors['default'] = defaultProcessor;
            rateProcessors[type] ?
                rateProcessors[type].getRates(quote.shippingAddress()) :
                rateProcessors['default'].getRates(quote.shippingAddress());

            // save rates to cache after load
            shippingService.getShippingRates().subscribe(function (rates) {
                cartCache.set('rates', rates);
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * Estimate totals for shipping address.
     */
    estimateTotalsShipping = function () {
        totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
    },

    /**
     * Estimate totals for billing address.
     */
    estimateTotalsBilling = function () {
        var type = quote.billingAddress().getType();

        if (quote.isVirtual()) {
            // update totals block when estimated address was set
            totalsProcessors['default'] = totalsDefaultProvider;
            totalsProcessors[type] ?
                totalsProcessors[type].estimateTotals(quote.billingAddress()) :
                totalsProcessors['default'].estimateTotals(quote.billingAddress());
        }
    };

quote.shippingAddress.subscribe(estimateTotalsAndUpdateRates);
quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(estimateTotalsShipping);
quote.billingAddress.subscribe(estimateTotalsBilling);
customerData.get('cart').subscribe(estimateTotalsShipping);
$("#co-shipping-method-form .item-options .field").prepend("<li>Prepended item</li>");
});
```

I need to prepend custom html with shipping methods list.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried along with your question for better understanding

Comment: I have updated question please check.